# Can You Specify Multiple Type Constraints For TypeScript Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic interface like this example with a single type constraint:

```
export interface IExample<T extends MyClass> {
    getById(id: number): T;
}
```

Is it possible to specify multiple type constraints instead of just one?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Typescript doesn't offer a syntax to get multiple inheritance for generic types. However, you can achieve similar semantics by using the Union types and Intersection types. In your case, you want an intersection :

```
interface Example<T extends MyClass & OtherClass> {}
```

For a Union of both types :

```
interface Example<T extends MyClass | OtherClass> {}
```

Comment: Union types are a great way to achieve this as you don't need to create an interface for the sole purpose of the constraint. They didn't exist back in 2013 - but this is definitely how I'd recommend doing it now.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Union types don't have the same semantics as extending two distinct types at all.

Comment: @AlexG Sure this is not the same as _extending_ two types but the same as _implementing_ two interfaces.

Comment: You need to change this to `T extends MyClass | OtherClass` to make this work. As things stand, T is expected to be both MyClass and OtherClass -- a single constraint.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Typescript supports intersection types as well. So `<T extends MyInterfaceA & MyInterfaceB>` requires that the type implement both interfaces.

Comment: As far as I understand semantic of `extends A|B` is extends A OR B as `extends A & B` is extend both! so maybe you should specify both in your answer....

Answer (score 42):

A work around for this would be to use a super-interface (which also answers the question "why would you allow an interface to inherit from a class").

```
interface ISuperInterface extends MyClass, OtherClass {

}

export interface IExample<T extends ISuperInterface> {
    getById(id: number): T;
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution. Extending an interface from two classes is kind of scary, though -- if both declare private members, the interface is unfulfillable

Answer (score 1):

Ref the comment about an interface deriving from a class...whats in a name?

I found this in section 3.5 of the 0.9.0 spec:

> Interface declarations only introduce named types, whereas class
>   declarations introduce named types and constructor functions that
>   create instances of implementations of those named types. The named
>   types introduced by class and interface declarations have only minor
>   differences (classes can’t declare optional members and interfaces
>   can’t declare private members) and are in most contexts
>   interchangeable. In particular, class declarations with only public
>   members introduce named types that function exactly like those created
>   by interface declarations.

Comment: Optional class members are now implemented: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8625