# Multiple collections in Angular-in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular, api, in-memory-database

How do we create **multiple** collections using **Angular-in-memory-web-api**?
Not an issue with single collection. But I'm not able to implement it for multiple collections.

For example, I want to create say two collections in the memory db - Country and Cities. Any idea, how to do that?

Answer (score 73):

Just return it an object with both arrays. In the example from Angular, you see something like

```ts
createDb() {
  let heroes = [ .. ]
  return { heroes }
}
```

If you don't already know this, `{ heroes }` is just shorthand for writing `{ heroes: heroes }`. So if you have two collections, then just add it as a another property

```ts
createDb() {
  let heroes = [ .. ];
  let crises = [ .. ];
  return { heroes, crises };
  // or { heroes: heroes, crises: crises }
}
```

The name of the property returned will be used for the path in the URL. So you can use

```
/api/heroes/1
/api/crises/1
```

Comment: That's great - but the **[heroes example](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)** also overwrites `genId(heroes: Hero[]): number { ... }`. Now I've tried to overload it to use `crises` as well (i.e. `genId(crises: Crises[]): number { ... }`), but no luck so far ("Duplicate function implementation"). How would you do that? (In the example, it returns the maximum id + 1 to be able to add new items)

Comment: Finally found a way to get it work and posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52931216/1016343) as additional info to your answer.

Answer (score 27):

The approach described in the [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40146891/1016343) is correct, however there is one detail I missed which I like to add: **How do you specify `genId` correctly, so it works for both collections?**

The answer is referring to the "Heroes" example written in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html) (a superset of JavaScript), specifically the [HTTP chapter](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6).
There, a table `heroes` is simulated by implementing:

```js
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      // ...
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }

  // Overrides the genId method to ensure that a hero always has an id.
  // If the heroes array is empty,
  // the method below returns the initial number (11).
  // if the heroes array is not empty, the method below returns the highest
  // hero id + 1.
  genId(heroes: Hero[]): number {
    return heroes.length > 0 ? Math.max(...heroes.map(hero => hero.id)) + 1 : 11;
  }
}
```

Now, if you add a **2nd collection `crises`** as shown in his answer, i.e.:

```js
createDb() {
  let heroes = [ { ... }, ... ];
  let crises = [ { ... }, ... ];
  return { heroes, crises };
  // or { heroes: heroes, crises: crises }
}
```

how do you provide `genId` for both collections (provided they are of type `Hero` and `Crises`)? Overloading, as you would do it in `C#` does not work in TypeScript, it would throw an error ("Duplicate function implementation").

---

**Solution:**
I found out, that you can solve this issue with **[TypeScript's Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)** as follows. Replace the otiginal `genId` function by the following generic version:

```js
genId<T extends Hero | Crises>(myTable: T[]): number {
  return myTable.length > 0 ? Math.max(...myTable.map(t => t.id)) + 1 : 11;
}
```

What's important here is the part `<T extends Hero | Crises>`: It means that type `T` can be either `Hero` or `Crises`: So it will be invoked if the parameter passed is either of type `Hero[]` or `Crises[]`.

With that knowledge, **adding a 3rd, 4th, ... class is simple:** Just append the class. Say we want to add the class `SuperHero`, then you just append it via `| SuperHero`, so it would look like:

```js
genId<T extends Hero | Crises | SuperHero>(myTable: T[]): number {
  return myTable.length > 0 ? Math.max(...myTable.map(t => t.id)) + 1 : 11;
}
```

**Note:** As a prerequisite, **all classes** (`Hero`, `Crises` and `SuperHero`) need to have a numeric `id` property declared.

---

**Useful links:**

- [HTTP chapter of Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#http)
- [In-Memory-Web-API: Custom genId](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api#custom-genid)
- [Can You Specify Multiple Type Constraints For TypeScript Generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17125764/1016343)

Comment: @ Matt, nice that you have included links to documentation / relevant articles 

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this discussion, I had to use Partial  as it kept on saying I was missing an id when completing the Tour of Heroes Lesson 06.  I used the message service to see how far the code went before it stopped working, so you can ignore the this.log lines, but you can add them to your own project to help with debugging.  First, I updated the addHero as follows:

`` addHero(hero: string): void {
    this.log(`In addHero of HeroesComponent, name is: ${hero}`);
if (!hero)
{
  this.log(`In if(!hero.name) of add hero: ${hero}`);
  return;
}

this.heroService.addHero({ name: hero } as Partial<Hero>)
  .subscribe(hero => {
    this.heroes.push(hero);
  });

} ``

And then I updated the heroes.service.ts file to use the partial hero and allow the code to generate its own id from the in-memory-data.service.ts:

`` addHero(hero: Partial): Observable {
    this.log(`In addHero: heroeName is: ${hero.name}`);
    
    return this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((newHero: Hero) =>
        this.log(`added hero with string id=${newHero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError("Error in addHero")));
  } ``

As far as I can see, it is now working as expected.  There may be some more code to update, but this should help anyone with the following error message:

`ERROR in src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts:52:30 - error TS2352: Conversion of type '{ name: never; }' to type 'Hero' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
Property 'id' is missing in type '{ name: never; }' but required in type 'Hero'.`