# How to restrict a generic interface from accepting a specific data type in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, web, interface

**How do I restrict a generic interface from accepting a specific data type in typescript?**

I know that to define what data types are acceptable to be passed in a generic interface in typescript.

```
interface exampleInterface<T = void | any>;
```

but what if I want restrict my interface from accepting one or two specific data types?

**Note:**
I have already viewed the following question and should mention that it is opposite of my question as it talks about how to define what data types ARE acceptable while I am trying to define what data types ARE NOT acceptable to be passed in this generic interface.

[Restricting generic types to one of several classes in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539710/restricting-generic-types-to-one-of-several-classes-in-typescript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting generic types to one of several classes in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539710/restricting-generic-types-to-one-of-several-classes-in-typescript)

Comment: @TobiasS. unfortunately no, because my question is about the opposite of this given solution, I want to be able to define what data types ARE NOT acceptable while in this given solution it is described how to to define what data types ARE acceptable

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to define a `type` like this:

```js
type NotAcceptable<T> = T extends string | undefined ? never : T
```

In this case `string` and `undefined` wouldn't be allowed.

You could then use it like this:

```js
let t1: NotAcceptable<string> = "abc"  // Error

function test<T>(t: NotAcceptable<T>){}

test("string")  // Error
test(undefined) // Error
test(123)       // Ok
```

The only downside to this is this being a `type` and not an `interface` as you specified in your question. But you can always use types like an interface and e.g. add props:

```
type NotAcceptable<T> = T extends string | undefined ? never : {
  abc: T
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=65&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAggY2RMwCGAjANhAHgBUA+KAXiiKggA9gIA7AEwGcpXgAnAS0YHMoAHygBXFhABmfCMygB+KIwgA3CFygAuKgCgd+YFGABGbfCSp0WPIU68BZSgCIcyJ3snjkwHnEZGITmISAApgMwQUNAwcfGCASgBvAF89Bk4Qpzs+fid4qCgAekKoAFEuLjguHXTgEPFmKRlmfOKyiqqawLrjACYAZnyC4aKSgHkAayA)