# How describe generic that can get different interfaces depends on situation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have situation when my component can get data in 1 case from
IDesigner interface in another from IDeveloper interface. So can I describe by type in this case?

I try this way but it's doesn't work

```
    interface ISummaryProps<T> {
      data: T;
    }
    
   interface IDesignerForm {
     name: string
   }

   interface IDeveloperForm {
    name: string,
    age: number
   }
   
    export const SummaryStep = <T extends IDesignerForm & IDeveloperForm>({
      data,
    }: ISummaryProps<T>): JSX.Element => {
     ...some jsx
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried  <T extends IDesignerForm | IDeveloperForm> ? a union instead of an and.

Comment: yes but in component I use data that doesnt belong to IDesigner in some cases or
IDeveloper so maybe I need use typeguard or something like this?

Comment: Do you know if this helps 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125764/can-you-specify-multiple-type-constraints-for-typescript-generics

Comment: or maybe <T extends IDesignerForm, DeveloperForm>