# Typescript generic interface function argument type inference error

Tags: javascript, typescript

Generic interface

```
export interface BaseService {
   getById<T extends number | string>(id: T): Promise<SomeType>;
}
```

And, the implementation

```
export class AService implements BaseService {
    async getById(id: number): Promise<SomeType> {
       // logic
    }

    //Other functions will be implemented here
}
```

And, the error I am getting:

```
Property 'getById' in type 'AService' is not assignable to the same property in base 
type 'BaseService'.
Type '(id: number) => Promise<SomeType>' is not assignable to type '<T extends 
string | number>(id: T) => Promise<SomeType>'.
Types of parameters 'id' and 'id' are incompatible.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2416)
```

Couple of things that I have tried:

```
getById<T extends number>(id: T): Promise<SomeType>; //This works, But I would have some methods with id type string
```

And,

```
getById<T>(id: T): Promise<SomeType>; //still compains
```

I have been following [Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). But, haven't encountered any similar thing.

**Would really appreciate any ideas or thoughts or any documentation!!**

Comment: Why are these methods generic? You don't _use_ the generic type parameter at all, which means they don't need to be generic at all. For example: https://tsplay.dev/wgAnlm

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue without unrelated problems when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  For example, errors because `BaseEntity` or `SpeciesEntity` are undefined, should be removed.

Comment: @AlexWayne, I am using the id: T which is generic. and Id could be another type

Comment: The generic type parameter in `getById<T extends number | string>(id: T)` let's you capture a type used for the argument `id` and use that type somewhere else, such as the return type of the method. But your return types do not depend on `T` at all. If you don't use `T` anywhere else, then you don't need it, and you're better off using the constraint as the argument type directly.

Comment: Type arguments for generic functions/methods are chosen by the *caller*, not the *implementer*.  If you have a value `s` of type `BaseService` (or any type that `extends` it), then you are allowed to call `s.getById("hello")` and `T` will be inferred as `"hello"`.  The implementer of `getById()` does not get to decide that `T` will be `number` or anything else.  It seems you want `BaseService` itself to be generic in the type of `id`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYRA3w); does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This could also an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125764/can-you-specify-multiple-type-constraints-for-typescript-generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getById<T extends number | string>(id: T): Promise<SomeType>` generic method is pretty pointless, that's more or less equivalent to just declaring a method of type `getById(id: number | string): Promise<SomeType>`.

I suspect what you actually want is

```
export interface BaseService<T extends number | string> {
    getById(id: T): Promise<SomeType>;
}
export class AService implements BaseService<number> {
//                                          ^^^^^^^^
    async getById(id: number): Promise<SomeType> {
        …
    }
    …
}
```

Comment: This is an answer. But I have a function that returns service based on a string and because of that I cant have BaseService<T> and Different service could have different T.

Comment: You can't, and shouldn't, have a function that returns a service without telling the caller whether it will be a service accepting a number or accepting a string (or both). You can declare it to return a `BaseService<never>` (and then return different services), but that won't be particularly useful.